# Set margin to entirely hide element from FrameLayout

Tags: android, animation, margin, android-framelayout

I have a Frame Layout with two child, one of which is a LinearLayout (search_filters), sits right under my toolbar.

```
    <!-- Your normal content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"
            android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/theme_primary"
            android:id="@+id/search_filters"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-200dp"/>
```

(unsure about how I set my marginTop)

The effect I am trying to achieve is to have the search_filters slide from top (out of screen) to the bottom of the toolbar.

slide in

```
    Animation a = new Animation() {

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) searchFilters.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin = -(int)(400 * (1-interpolatedTime));
            searchFilters.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(300); // in ms
    a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    searchFilters.startAnimation(a);
```

and

slide away

```
    Animation a = new Animation() {

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) searchFilters.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin = -(int)(400 * interpolatedTime);
            searchFilters.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(300); // in ms
```

android.R.interpolator.fast_out_slow_in);
        a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

```
    searchFilters.startAnimation(a);
```

The issue is that the "400" is completely arbitrary and not working on all devices (working on my nexus 4 but not my galaxy s4).

How do I change my code so that the view consistently goes away (say +25% for satefy and animation) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the height of the screen using

```
height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
```

And then, use this value as the topMargin to complete hide the view from the screen.

```
 params.topMargin = -(int)(height * interpolatedTime);
```

You can also find the height of your view using

```
mView.measure(0,0);
mViewHeight = mView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

And then use that value as the margin.

**EDIT : ** Or to make it even easier, use percentage values in the XML of the animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Comment: there is a chance of the view going too far up, and therefore my animation to look really weird... right? Any chance I can achieve height of my view +25%?

Comment: Updated my answer with two more possible solutions. :)

Comment: I'll try them thanks. Very interested in the last one... never used set. Do you need to put an id? How do you call it in the code?

Comment: Animation topIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in); itemChoicesContainer.startAnimation(topIn);

Comment: Thanks so much. The first one works. Regarding the animation resource, it doesn't seem to work. I had to remove the view's initial margin in my xml. Then the animation works fine, but the new Y doesn't seem to persist after it... any guess?

Comment: don't say! topIn.setFillAfter(true). BOOOOM!
Thanks so much